# Python2.7 & SQLite3: DELETE & SELECT with DATE(SUBSTR()) DO NOT working

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, date, select, sql-delete

Firstly, I have a table in SQLlite3 with two fields `CAR (TEXT NOT NULL)`, `checkout (TEXT NOT NULL)`

```
car checkout
red %d%d/%m%m/%Y (for example 27/09/2021)
```

Second, I wrote a script which the structure is when I run it, all the entries that current date is equal or bigger than checkout to be deleted.

Third, in the same script with SELECT to check if the car is in the list and checkout is bigger than current date exclude from my available cars.

The code snippet makes the first step is the following:

```py
try:
con = lite.connect(DB)
with con:
    paper=[]
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM CHECK_TABLE WHERE DATE(substr(checkout,7,4)||substr(checkout,4,2)||substr(checkout,1,2))<=DATE(strftime('%Y%m%d',date('now')))")
    con.commit()
    print('Entries with old dates deleted.')
except lite.Error as e:
        print('Error connection: ',e)
```

The problem is **that is not deleting anything**. The strange behaviour is firstly that the **SQL query works** in DB Browser,
[Image: Proof DB Browser in Windows 10 - Python2.7 - SQLite3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILoYg.jpg)
the second strange behaviour is that **no error is raising** and the third strange is that **I tested two days ago and it worked normally!** I really need your thoughts.

The same logic is in the following code snippet which is the the third step that I described above with SELECT command.

```py
def ReadDateAndCar(car):
try:
    con = lite.connect(DB)
    with con:
        paper=[]
        cur=con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT car FROM CHECK_TABLE WHERE car='"+car+"' AND DATE(substr(checkout,7,4)||substr(checkout,4,2)||substr(checkout,1,2))<=DATE(strftime('%Y%m%d',date('now')))")
        free_cars=cur.fetchall()
        return free_cars
except lite.Error as e:
    print('Error connection: ',e)
    return 0
```

Exactly the same problems. SQL query works fine, no python error is raising, it worked few days ago. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d0cd2318f4e07e21fe03ea0c2aede4a1 Can you reproduce with sample data here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 your DELETE query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your queries are wrong and they don't work in DB Browser either.

What you should do is store the dates with the ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`, because this is the only text date format compatible with SQLite's datetime functions like `date()` and `strftime()` and it is comparable.
If you use any other format the result of these functions is `null` and this is what happens in your case.

The expressions `substr(checkout,7,4)||substr(checkout,4,2)||substr(checkout,1,2)` and `strftime('%Y%m%d',date('now'))` return dates in the format `YYYYMMDD` and if you use them inside `date()` or `strftime()` the result is `null`.

Since you obtain in both sides of the inequality dates in the format `YYYYMMDD` then they are directly comparable and you should not use the function `date()`.

The condition should be:

```
substr(checkout, -4) || substr(checkout, 4, 2) || substr(checkout, 1, 2) <= strftime('%Y%m%d', 'now')
```

Comment: I suppose the null result is a correct result for Python2.7 which explains, probably, why no error is rising, but your query worked for me and I really appreciate your answer. I would like some time to test further. I was looking something like str2date(string, separator,final format) where it takes string (for example 27/09/2021), separator="/" and final format "%Y-%m-%d" for example ISO format and converts string to date which means the command should return date for further actions.

Comment: @vatan SQLite does not support functions that transform strings to dates, because there is no DATE data type in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html This is why you should always define dates as TEXT and store them in ISO format.